# Unable print variable into CSV in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Unable to write `user_status` and `username` into CSV and also print name into CSV. When JSON data `"changed"="true"` then print user has been created. Otherwise `"changed"="false"` the print user already exists. And also print name into CSV.

```yaml
- name: Final sheet for user id creation
  shell: echo "{{ item }}","{{ user_status }}" >> /file/id_creation.csv 
  loop: "{{ useroutput }}"
```

Please find below JSON data. Its output of `useroutput`.

```json
useroutput: {
      "msg": "All items", 
 "results": [
    {     
        "changed": false, 
        "item": "uxapal1007", 
        "name": "uxapal1007"
    }, 


    {
        "changed": true, 
        "item": "uxapal1008",
        "name": "uxapal1008"
     },

       {
        "changed": true, 
        "item": "uxapal1009",
        "name": "uxapal1009"
      }

          ]
        }
```

Don't know how use `set_fact` for list of dict. Kindly help. Didn't write code of `set_fact` for `user_status`. Unable to write `username` and `user_status` into CSV. Kindly help me out.

Expected output:

```
uxapal1007  user has already present 
uxapal1008  user has been created
uxapal1009  user has been created
```

[Should CSV generate like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrIAx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lineinfile module for this to create the file, write the headers and the rows like this:

Example of playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    useroutput: {
      "msg": "All items", 
    "results": [
        {     
            "changed": false, 
            "item": "uxapal1007", 
            "name": "uxapal1007"
        }, 


        {
            "changed": true, 
            "item": "uxapal1008",
            "name": "uxapal1008"
        },

        {
            "changed": true, 
            "item": "uxapal1009",
            "name": "uxapal1009"
        }

            ]
            }
  tasks:
    - name: Create csv file first
      lineinfile: 
        path: "{{ csv_path }}"
        line: User_id,User_id_status
        state: present
        create: True
      run_once: True
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: write to csv file if user was created
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ csv_path }}"
        line: "{{ item.name }},user has been created"
        state: present
      delegate_to: localhost
      loop: "{{ useroutput.results }}"
      when: item.changed

    - name: write to csv file if user already existed
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ csv_path }}"
        line: "{{ item.name }},user is already present"
        state: present
      delegate_to: localhost
      loop: "{{ useroutput.results }}"
      when: not item.changed
```

Give in csv file:

```
User_id,User_id_status
uxapal1008,user has been created
uxapal1009,user has been created
uxapal1007,user is already present
```